# Ionic mobile app synchronization between users design

Tags: android, angularjs, couchdb, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm developing mobile Ionic app. The app's purpose is this, for logging rides to work, who drived and who's passengers. It's simple until you want to synchronize if between many users. The app is almost finished, but I'm struggling with this. I don't know how to figure out conflicts between records.
I'm using Ionic mobile framework so the app is in angularjs and as database I'm using PouchDB and I want to synchronize it to remote CouchDB.

Can you give my some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just added a guide to conflict resolution to the PouchDB web site: http://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html